# Blank Screen between a SplashScreen and webview in phonegap iOS

Tags: javascript, ios, html, cordova

How can I avoid the blank white screen appearing between the phonegap splashscreen and webview loading stage in iOS.I have followed the suggested solutions..like
  [1]: http://docs.phonegap.com/en/2.5.0/cordova_splashscreen_splashscreen.md.html#Splashscreen,and other but still the white screen persists even after setting time delay.

```
I'm loading a external mobile website inside my local index.html file using window.location.href.
```

Thanks

Answer (score 0):

Try removing page transitions, This helped me to some extent, and use latest phonegap. Use the following code before including jquery mobile library.

```
$(document).bind("mobileinit", function(){
$.mobile.defaultPageTransition="none"
});
```

Edit: Oops, it was  between splash screen and the first screen. Try this
[link](https://stackoverflow.com/questions/11300778/white-screen-flash-after-launch-image-using-phonegap)